# What is better, a large number of intervals or one cycle?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that the number of intervals itself does not load the system in any way, however, what if their number is large? I need to update the data of the entities and for this there are two options:

1. Create an interval once for each entity, which once every 1 second will perform the corresponding actions.
2. Create one interval for all entities, which once every 1 second will cycle through all entities and perform appropriate actions.

It is important to note that it does not matter to me whether the entities will be updated at the same time or not. Approximate number of entities: from 0 to 1500. NodeJS application.

Comment: What "intervals" are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the total update duration is short (<20ms), you would most likely prefer to update them all at once

```
function up() {
  for (let e of entities) e.update();
}
setInterval(up, 1000)
```

2. If each update is long (>4ms), you would most likely prever to execute them in a sequence, to awoid unordering and staggering (you do have some parallel thing like IO/http/ws)

```
import { setImmediate, setTimeout } from 'node:timers/promises'
async function up() {
  for (let e of entities) {
    e.update();
    await setImmediate();
  }
}
async function upForever(){
  while(true){
    let now = performance.now();
    await up();
    let sleep = now + 1000 - performance.now();
    if (sleep > 0) await setTimeout(sleep)
  }
}
```